# Set a default text in an article

Tags: nodes, theming

Im looking for a way to create a text template or a way to make one, where, when you create a node of a specific content type, a text is preloaded into the node. (Similar to Word-Templates)

At the moment, whenever I habe to write a status report, I have to copy paste it, but I want this to happen automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the default value for the body field to your text template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple options come to mind,

if you don't want to code then you can use [Node Clone](https://drupal.org/project/node_clone) module and have 1 unpublished template node, and everytime you want to create a new one just clone the template node.

Also without installing any modules, you can use the `Default value` in the field setting of the content type

The other way is a bit more tricky, you have to create a custom module and use [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to set the default values of the fields for your specific content type.